# {Date_Repeat} Every day of the week doesn't work

Tags: datetime

This question is in regards with Date module (date_repeat)

I am setting the frequency date to "every" "weeks" until a certain time with the following advanced setting:

Day of the week: Every Saturday

but the result doesn't respect my advanced setting and it will repeat the date every "seven days" regardless the length of the month

How do I fix this?

- I am using Node Repeat for this purpose.

Comment: this looks like something that should be in the issue queue for the Node Repeat module rather than here.

Comment: I have actually added that to the queue as well but was wondering if someone can help here too?

Comment: maybe, but from your description this sounds like a bug in the module rather than something set up by design

Comment: I think it is a buy too, was wondering if someone has experienced the same and know the solution here?

Comment: that said, can you give an example of a week that isn't 7 days long? ie. when would "every 7 days, starting Sat" not be equal to "every Sat"?

Comment: I know if you add 7 days it should work, but it doesn't for some reason, this is what I do in the backend:

http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/8099/repeat1.png

and here is the result that I got:

http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/1656/repeat2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance that in your time zone there's a [Daylight Saving Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) change on [Saturday, November 6](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2011b.html) ? Like for exemple in [Los Angeles](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=137).
Because this would explain the shift of one hour you get after the 5th of November (remember, remember :) ).

> **Inspiration**: OMG Ponies!!! (Aka Humanity: Epic Fail), Jon Skeet -
>   Stack Overflow Dev Days London 2009, [video](http://vimeo.com/7516539) and [transcript](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx).